# Add class in Checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I am using onepge checkout in `Magento1`, now I want to add class in **subtotal** section like here is class last I want add new class how I do that wihout using `jquery`

```
<tr class="last">
    <td style="" class="a-right" colspan="2">
        <strong>Grand Total</strong>
    </td>
<td style="" class="a-right last"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy : `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tax/checkout/grandtotal.phtml`

To:

`app/design/frontend/{YourTheme}/{name}/template/tax/checkout/grandtotal.phtml`

```
<tr class="Your-new-class-name-here"> //here
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <strong><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Grand Total Incl. Tax')?></strong>
    </td>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
        <strong><?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getTotal()->getValue()) ?></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
```

`subtotal.phtml` for **subtotal**.